# How to avoid duplicate entries crawling a site

Tags: ruby, web-crawler, nokogiri, mechanize

I want to crawl a shop with Ruby, Nokogiri and Mechanize.

On a page with two articles shown, I know that all articles start with `.../p/...` in the address so that's why I store this in `article_links`. All `/p/` links should be displayed.

Normally I would see two addresses:

```
agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get(exampleshop.com)

article_links = page.links_with(href: %r{.*/p/})

article_links.map do |link|
    article = link.click
    target_URL = page.uri + link.uri #full URL
    puts "#{target_URL}"
end   
#crawling stuff on /p/ pages not included here
```

However, in the end each link is duplicated, which already happens before the loop, so I get to see:

```
exampleshop.com/p/productxy.html

exampleshop.com/p/productxy.html

exampleshop.com/p/productab.html

exampleshop.com/p/productab.html
```

I believe that there are two hrefs with `/p/` for each product in the site's code. Is there a good way to prevent this? Or is it possible to use Nokogiri CSS in `links_with`?

Comment: It's difficult to duplicate the problem without sample HTML. See "[mcve]". `map` is the wrong iterator for this. You should use `each` if you don't need to assign a modified value as you loop over `article_links`. `map` is going to return the same things that are assigned to `target_URL`, so depending on how that snippet of code is used it could result in duplicate information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove the duplicates before iterating over the list:

Instead of

```
article_links.map do |link|
```

write

```
article.links.uniq { |link| link.uri }.map do |link|
```

which will remove any links with a duplicate uri.

You could use [CSS regex selectors](http://thegeekyway.com/css-regex-selector-using-regular-expression-css/) instead of `links_with`, but you'd still need to remove duplicates in Ruby:

```
article_links = page.css("a[href*='/p/']")
```

The reason you'd still need to remove duplicates in Ruby is that CSS has no way to select the first element of a match. [nth-of-type](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) or [nth-child](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp) wouldn't work here.